# Symfony2: How to add/remove entry forms for the collection field type?

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form that contains a collection field-type.

However I don't know how to add/remove fields to/from the collection.

```
$builder        
    // ...              
    ->add('covers', 'collection', array(
          'required'     => false,
          'type'         => new BookCoverType(),
          'allow_add'    => true,
    )) 
;
```

The rendered form looks like this:

[image]

How can I add a new cover using the collection form field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony does **not** provide the add/remove JavaScript methods/buttonss or any session-based solution without JavaScript out of the box.

It renders a `data-prototype` attribute that can be used as described in the documentation chapter **[How to Embed a Collection of Forms -> Allowing "new" tags with the "prototype"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype)**.

Some bundles provide this functionality though. Those are primarily the bootstrap bundles:

- [braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle](https://github.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle)
- [mopa/bootstrap-bundle](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle)
- ...

Just dive into their code - i.e. braincrafted/bootstrapbundle's **[bc-bootstrap-collection.js](https://github.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle/blob/develop/Resources/js/bc-bootstrap-collection.js)**.

Comment: But my code is correct? I can make in js uploading without problem - and then I will have to make new BookCover in controller manually from $_FILES?